# Set Value to a Prompt Input in Python

Tags: python, linux

My goal is to create a user using python script to execute linux command.

---

I have

```
import os
import fileinput


username = raw_input("Enter username : ")
os.system("adduser -m "+username )
os.system("passwd "+username )

----> STUCK <----

os.system("usermod -aG sudo "+username )
os.system("chsh -s /bin/bash "+username )
```

---

How do we programmatically provide data/value to a prompt input ?

Comment: Not sure if this will work, but try `os.system("echo {PASSWORD-HERE} | passwd " + username)`.

Comment: Let me try. Nice. Thanks for suggesting.

Comment: Another slightly more complicated approach is to use a pseudo terminal `pty` and a pipe to communicate with the `passwd` process. I used this approach in c when communicating with ssh. I can't immediately provide a solution, but this might set you off in the right direction. You might find it easier using `POpen` than `os.system`.

Comment: Ok. I'll look into it. Thanks for suggestion Paul :)